# Вычислительная геометрия

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Даны два треугольника на плоскости – ABC и DEF определяются координатами своих вершин:  А(1,1), B(2,2), C(3,4), D(2,1), E(1,3), F(3,3). Определить, пересекаются эти треугольники или нет.

Каков алгоритм определения, пересекаются или нет? =(

Comment: ow.com/questions/1585459/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-triangle-triangle-

Answer (score 4):

Надо найти [пересечение отрезков](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segments_intersection) сторон треугольников каждой с каждой. Будет 8 проверок в худшем случае.

Answer (score 3):

Можно проверить на нахождение точек в треугольнике (для пересечения должны находиться 1-2 точки внутри другого треугольника), в худшем случае 6 проверок. [тут обсуждают "Точка в треугольнике"](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=17046)

Comment: А разве "проверка нахождения точек в треугольнике" работает в том случае, когда точки не входят в треугольники?

Comment: @IVsevolod какие точки будем выбирать? если речь о вершинах, то для "звезды давида" будет ложный результат...

Comment: А если один треугольник целиком внутри второго - то проверка пересечений не поможет

Comment: Значит, для полноты картины нужно комбинировать два метода. Если хоть один из них вернул true, то пересечение есть. Можно ещё делать предварительную проверку по [AABB][1], чтобы не запускать эти методы для заведомо не пересекающихся треугольников.

  [1]: http://www.gamedev.ru/terms/AABB

Comment: все верно, нужна комбинация.

Comment: ой, точно ))) для случаев типа "Звезды давида" не учел )

Answer (score -2):

Вот изобрел способ проверки пересечения 2D фигур любой формы. Его можно легко переделать (функция checkCrossing) для того чтобы узнавать сколько раз пересекает одна фигура другую и координаты где пересекает. Не знаю правда насколько эффективен такой алгоритм.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct point{
    double x, y;

    bool operator == (const point p){
        if ((x == p.x) && (y == p.y))
      return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
} p;

vector<point> buf;

void linesArray(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    const double deltaX = abs(x2 - x1);
    const double deltaY = abs(y2 - y1);
    const double signX = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1;
    const double signY = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;

    double error = deltaX - deltaY;

        p.x = x2;
        p.y = y2;

        buf.push_back(p);

    while(x1 != x2 || y1 != y2) {

            p.x = x1;
            p.y = y1;

            buf.push_back(p);

        const double error2 = error * 2;

        if(error2 > -deltaY) {
            error -= deltaY;
            x1 += signX;
        }

        if(error2 < deltaX) {
            error += deltaX;
            y1 += signY;
        }
    }
}

bool checkCrossing(){   // функция вернет истину если один многоугольник пересекается с другим
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < buf.size(); j++){
            if ((buf[i] == buf[j]) && (i != j))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    // загружаем стороны 1 многоугольника
    linesArray(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0); // A и B
    linesArray(2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0); // B и C
    linesArray(3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0); // C и A

    // загружаем стороны 2 многоугольника
    linesArray(2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0); // D и E
    linesArray(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0); // E и F
    linesArray(3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0); // F и D

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    buf.clear();

    // ещо проверка (тест - должно совпасть)
    linesArray(1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0); 
    linesArray(0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    buf.clear();

    // ещо проверка (тест - не должно совпасть)
    linesArray(1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0); 
    linesArray(1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

***_НОВЫЙ ИСПРАВЛЕННЫЙ КОД******_******_******_******_******_***__

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct point{
    double x, y;

        bool operator == (const point p){
            if ((x == p.x) && (y == p.y))
          return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    } p;

    vector<point> buf;

     void round (double & x, int precision){     // ДОБАВЛЕНО
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++){
      res *= 10;
    }

    x = x * res;
}

                                                                                                                        // точьность (сколько знаков после запятой)!!!!
void linesArray(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, int precision = 1) {
    round(x1, precision);   // ДОБАВЛЕНО
    round(y1, precision);   // ДОБАВЛЕНО
    round(x2, precision);   // ДОБАВЛЕНО
    round(y2, precision);   // ДОБАВЛЕНО

  const double deltaX = abs(x2 - x1);
  const double deltaY = abs(y2 - y1);
  const double signX = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1;
  const double signY = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;

  double error = deltaX - deltaY;

    p.x = x2;
    p.y = y2;

    buf.push_back(p);

  while((x1 != x2) || (y1 != y2)) {

        p.x = x1;
        p.y = y1;

        buf.push_back(p);

      const double error2 = error * 2;

      if(error2 > -deltaY) {
          error -= deltaY;
          x1 += signX;
      }

      if(error2 < deltaX) {
          error += deltaX;
          y1 += signY;
      }
   }
}

bool checkCrossing(){   // функция вернет истину если один многоугольник пересекается с другим
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < buf.size(); j++){
            if ((buf[i] == buf[j]) && (i != j))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    // загружаем стороны 1 многоугольника
    linesArray(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0); // A и B
    linesArray(2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0); // B и C
    linesArray(3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0); // C и A

    // загружаем стороны 2 многоугольника
    linesArray(2.3, 1.3, 1.0, 3.0); // D и E      
    linesArray(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0); // E и F
    linesArray(3.0, 3.0, 2.3, 1.3); // F и D

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    buf.clear();

    // ещо проверка (тест - должно совпасть)
    linesArray(1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0); 
    linesArray(0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    buf.clear();

    // ещо проверка (тест - не должно совпасть)
    linesArray(1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0); 
    linesArray(1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    // проверяем на пересечение
    if (checkCrossing())
        cout << "yes crossing" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No crossing"  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему минусуете без комментариев?

Comment: Это тяжелый случай просто. Запустите с:

    // загружаем стороны 1 многоугольника
    linesArray(1.1, 1.1, 2.0, 2.0); // A и B
    linesArray(2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0); // B и C
    linesArray(3.0, 4.0, 1.1, 1.1); // C и A

    // загружаем стороны 2 многоугольника
    linesArray(2.3, 1.3, 1.0, 3.0); // D и E
    linesArray(1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0); // E и F
    linesArray(3.0, 3.0, 2.3, 1.3); // F и D

Comment: исправил код, теперь можно задавать точность вычислений (функция linesArray -> последний аргумент - сколько знаков используется после запятой). прошу оценить

Comment: Какой-то странный алгоритм, если для него принципиальна точность записи числа? В чем его суть? Я не очень в Си.

Comment: алгоритм

1) записываем все точки отрезков первого объекта (стороны многоугольника)(линия же состоит точек) в массив.
2) записываем все точки отрезков второго объекта в этот же массив.
3)теперь мы имеем набор точек и их координат первого и второго объекта, если в массиве есть точки с одинаковыми координатами значит где то фигура1 пересекается с фигурой2 (это делает функция checkCrossing).

ps
функцию checkCrossing например можно переделать так что бы по подсчету одинаковым координатам точек можно было узнать сколько у фигур точек пересечения и их координаты пересечения и т.п

Comment: проблема этого алгоритма в типе double потому что этот тип нужен для точности вычислений (например в жизни). но для компьютерной графики  подходит больше.

если использовать этот алгоритм в компьютерной графики в качестве объектов в этом алгоритме можно использовать любую фигуру даже круг или шестигранник потому что они состоят из прямых линий (наборы точек).

Comment: О_О  (смайлик выпученных глаз)  
То есть для расчета пересечения двух линий размером 1 млрд точек мы создадим два массива по гигабайту и потом пробежимся по этому массиву, вместо того, чтобы просто сложить/отнять/разделить/сравнить ?

Comment: @perfect, извините, но это лютый п**ц. Что по вашему значит фраза "два треугольника пересекаются"?

Comment: @perfect тэги вопроса смотрели? речь не о компьютерной графике, к которой ваш алгоритм тоже не применим, т.к. точки в компьютерной графике даже для прямых не лежат на одной геометрической прямой (кроме горизонталей и вертикалей).  
Геометрическую задачу также вы сразу не решили, т.к. точки пересечения будут довольно часто иррациональными и никогда не попадут в ваши массивы. Алгоритм не пройдет и половины тестов, предварительно разорив вас на планках, да и слотов не хватит для них...

Comment: Ну нет. Точка пересечения двух прямых линий всегда выражается отношением двух вещественных чисел, а значит - всегда рационально. Уточню - если коэффициенты уравнения прямой рациональны

Comment: ну да, загнул слегка )

Comment: Иррациональность может появиться, если хотя бы одна из линий - нелинейное уравнение. Очень повеселило представление, что, цитирую "линия состоит из точек". Это еще в апориях Зенона было хорошо показано, что ведет к парадоксам. "Число" точек из которой состоит прямая (и даже любой ее отрезок), мощность множества иными словами, равна мощности континуума.